# How to load partials into view?

Tags: angularjs, root, partial

I am trying to load partials into rooted page, with no luck so far.
I have a promo-page with thumbs, which are different according to their type: [wireframe](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zhliyf&s=8#.VBmKgi5dXZg).

It works fine when it is not loaded into rooted page:
[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjZxFfgoFt8rshL15ncw?p=preview)

This is example where I am trying to load partials: [plunker example 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/IibcdYpjDEadozUeAJEW?p=preview)

```
myApp.directive('contentItem', function ($compile, $parse) {

    templates = {
      image: 'image.html',
      event: 'event.html',
      article: 'article.html',
      ad: 'ad.html',
      discount: 'discount.html',
      video: 'video.html'

    }

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.setUrl = function(){
          return templates[scope.content.content_type];
        }

    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: linker,
        scope: {
          content: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    };
});
```

Could you advice me please how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by rooted page?

Comment: Sorry for that - I meant - ngRoute --> into view. Does it make sense?

Comment: Looks to me like `promo.html` is shown correctly in the `ng-view` `div`

Comment: Promo.html is loading, but it is not loading partials inside.

Comment: huh? I think you are misunderstanding something here. With your current code why and how would you expect a partial to be shown inside the `promo.html` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was so much fundamentally wrong with your app, stupid small mistakes that would have taken you 5 minutes to sort out if you would have had a look at the js console.

I fixed your [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/AmsZQ5udSshJYK9fXUII?p=preview) here.

You had forgotten JQuery as a dependency, also you had forgotten to define a controller which you clearly use some where. And the list goes on.